# I am using Writer and OutputStream In one Class so how can i control?

Tags: java

I'm designing a library where a class should have an ability to be able to convert itself internals into text. Which class shall I use: `OutputStream` or `Writer`? And what is the key difference between them (in my case)?

Comment: Depends on what do you want to do with the text : write it into a file, send it by socket, make a XML document... Convert internal variables into text can be done without an `OutputStream`

Comment: WTF... this isn't just a duplicate, it's an exact copy of the first paragraph of that question. What's the point?

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is that a `Stream` writes bytes (binary data) while a `Writer` writes characters (text).

Choose what best fits your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your responding so u please provide solution for this ?